# Rails STI sibling callbacks propagating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, ruby-on-rails-5, sti

I'm facing an issue with STI (single table inheritance), where a callback that should only run on one of a child model's instances, actually runs on its sibling's instances as well, even though it shouldn't.

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord; end

class FirstChild < Parent
  after_initialize :set_default_attr

  private
  def set_default_attr
    self.attr = "something"
  end
end

class SecondChild < Parent; end

second = SecondChild.new
assert_nil second.attr # Fails because it is set to "something"
```

I expect the `#set_default_attr` callback to run only on `FirstChild` instances, not on `SecondChild` ones. I think the current behaviour is counter-intuitive. Am I missing something?

Ruby version: 2.5.0, Rails version: 5.1.4

---

**Update 1:** It seems like also validations propagate

**Update 2:** A possible workaround would be to add something like this:

```
class FirstChild < Parent
  after_initialize :set_default_attr, if: :type_is_first?
  validate :attr, presence: true, if: :type_is_first?

  private
  def set_default_attr
    self.attr = "something"
  end

  def type_is_first?
    type == "FirstChild"
  end
end
```

however this feels super dirty to me.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I was inheriting from a wrong class...